# Report errors for different content-types in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have a simple Sinatra app with normal and JSON API parts. I would like to create an error block:

```
error do
  # ...
end
```

that would return a JSON in format { :error => "some text" } in case the client sent **Accept header** set to *application/json*, and remain default Sinatra behavior for all other cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read the header within the error block as the argument to a conditional, and a helper method for choosing the output:

e.g

```
def content_to( output, type=nil )
  case type
    when "application/json"
      #...
    else
      output
  end...

error do
  content_to( "Whoops!", header["Accept"] )
end
```

Comment: just thought I'd add, you might want to also set the content type, e.g. `content_type :json` when returning it.

Comment: See Sinatra::RespondWith for a ready made helper http://rubydoc.info/gems/sinatra-contrib/1.3.1/frames